# iOS:is that available to control or choose the way to receive message from network?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I want to force the device to receive the data from network with 3G/4G service when the  Wifi is connected.
Do developers have the permission/API to control which network device to use?is there any document about this in Apple Developer Library?

Answer (score 0):

Reachability class use this. Search from google.

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];
NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

With Reachability you can only get info about what connection is currently available.

Why would you want to anyway?